# Pyspark performance issue spark 1.5.2 distributors cloudera

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-1.5.2

I experience some performance issues when executing following PySpark script:

```
import os
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.context import SQLContext, HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.types import Row


def append_columns(row, dct):
    """
    :param row:
    :param dct:
    :type row:Row
    :type dct:dict
    :return:
    """
    schema = row.asDict()
    schema.update(dct)
    return Row(**schema)


def append_column(row, key, value):
    """
    :param row:
    :param key:
    :param value:
    :type row:Row
    :type key: str
    :return:
    """
    schema = row.asDict()
    if key not in schema:
        schema[key] = value
    res = Row(**schema)
    return res


class Components(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def first_components(self, row, key):
        """
        :param row:
        :param key:
        :type row: Row
        :type key:lambda for example labmda x: x.description
        :return:
        """
        pass

    def join(self, row, dict_other, key):
        """
        some logic with join
        :param row:
        :param dict_other:
        :param key:
        :return:
        :rtype: list
        was realized joining logic like "one to many" multiply per row ~150->1500

        """
        pass

    def some_action(self, x, key):
        pass


def append_category(row, key, is_exists_category, type_category):
    comp = Components()
    if int(is_exists_category) == 1:
        type_category = int(type_category)
        if type_category == 1:
            return append_column(row, "component", comp.first_components(row, key))
        elif type_category == 2:
            """
            copy paste
            """
            return append_column(row, "component", comp.first_components(row, key))
    else:
        return row


comp = Components()
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sql = SQLContext(sparkContext=sc)
query = HiveContext(sparkContext=sc)
first = sql.parquetFile("some/path/to/parquetfile").rdd.collectAsMap()
first = sc.broadcast(first)
key = lambda x: x.description
"""sec has from select 2k rows"""
sec = query.sql("select bla, bla1, description from some_one").rdd \
    .filter(lambda x: x.bla1 > 10) \
    .map(lambda x: append_category(x, key, 1, 1)) \
    .map(lambda x: append_column(x, "hole_size", comp.some_action(x, key))) \
    .flatMap(lambda x: comp.join(x, first.value, key)) \
    .filter(lambda x: x)
table = 'db.some_one'
query.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {tbl}".format(tbl=table + "_test"))
query.createDataFrame(sec, samplingRatio=10).saveAsTable("{tbl}".format(tbl=table + "_dcka"), mode='overwrite',
                                                         path=os.path.join("some/path/to/",
                                                                           table.split('.')[1] + "_test"))
```

Spark configuration:

- 6 executors
- 2GB per executors

This script run almost 5 hours and Spark history shows load only on a single executor. Partitioning doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Hi, found what was issue. (Problem with cluster and libs. also but implement logic of joining) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try simplifying your logic bit by bit:

```
rdd1 = query.sql("select bla, bla1, description from some_one").rdd
rdd2 = sql.parquetFile("some/path/to/parquetfile").rdd
rdd1.join (rdd2)
```

then add filtering, then broadcast join if performance sucks

You can monitor number of your partitions via 'rdd.partitions.size', number of your partitions should roughly correspond to amount of cores on the whole cluster so that all of the executors are involved in processing